# How do machines without RTC generate pseudorandom numbers?

Tags: language-agnostic, random

I always wondered how some old game consoles like the NES were able to generate random numbers without a seed like time(NULL);

Thanks

Comment: The page: http://tasvideos.org/RandomGenerators.html describes the implementation of the random number generators on several NES games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the time between subsequent key presseses, joystick movement or any similar human originated interaction. If you can time the events for example in microseconds and take modulo 100 or so you end with a reasonable seed. If needed you can also do this several times to harvest enough bits to create a big enough (i.e. 64 bits) seed.

On some other systems that cannot depend on human interaction for the seed, the reset circuit uses a RC circuit but component variations will make this time slightly different on every system. An external (CPU independent counter) can be started on power up and then read by the CPU during start up. If the counter has enough resolution relative to the reset circuit time constant then the last bits can be used as a seed. This was used long time ago by networked devices to generated the MAC-equivalent address before the Ethernet era.

--ga